# Import in Perl like Python 'import as'

Tags: perl

Does Perl have something like python's `import as`?

If the modules don't specify a package, this hacky little solution could work:

```
# mod1.pm
sub routine{ return "I'm from mod1\n"; }
```

```
# mod2.pm
sub routine{ return "I'm from mod2\n"; }
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

# similar to 'import mod1 as foo'
package foo;
require 'mod1.pm';

# similar to 'import mod2 as bar'
package bar;
require 'mod2.pm';

# now do some script stuff
package main;
print foo::routine();
print bar::routine();
```

This doesn't work if the modules come with their own namespace:

```
# ABC.pm
package ABC;
sub routine{ return "I'm from ABC\n"; }
```

```
# DEF.pm
package DEF;
sub routine{ return "I'm from DEF\n"; }
```

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

package foo;
require 'ABC.pm';

package bar;
require 'DEF.pm';

package main;
print foo::routine();
print bar::routine();

# These calls produce undefined subroutine errors.
```

Is it possible to import a file, and force its contents into a specific namespace?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? This feels like an XY problem.

Comment: Do you have controll over `ABC.pm` and `foo.pm`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm bad for asking XY questions.. I like them for helping to understand how stuff works, even if it's not good practice to use the answers for real. The community doesn't seem to like them though, so I guess I should get out of the habit?

Comment: The community has been burned on many occasions by chasing around after hypothetical questions that present bad solutions to non problems. There's nothing wrong with questions asking how stuff works, but it helps to be clear that's what you're doing - as a question about how perl's symbol table works, this is fine. However messing around with the symbol table is often a route to madness, and there's _generally_ better solutions to a particular problem.

Comment: I agree with @Sobrique. Also I got sidetracked by the title. There is indeed a way to import something as something else in Perl, with [aliased](http://p3rl.org/aliased). That's what I answered first after only reading the title. The question however, asked for something else entirely. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the description I assume you controll neither `ABC` nor `foo`.

Because there are no `import` subs in either of those two, all their subs live in their respective pacakges. So if you load `foo`, `ABC` will also be loaded and the code will be available to Perl. But the sub in `ABC` is only accessible with its fully qualified name `ABC::routine`.

In fact that is the same as when LWP::UserAgent `require`s HTTP::Request. Now you can use HTTP::Request without a `use HTTP::Request` in your code. You only put `use LWP::UserAgent` there, and since that loaded the other one, it's now available.

Of course those do not export stuff, so it's a bit different, but that is essentially what's going on here.

---

**However, without controll of at least `foo.pm` there is no way to counter that.** You cannot overwrite a `package` statement or declare some part of the program where `package` doesn't do anything.

---

To go a bit further, you probably are used to legacy code, where there are `.pl` files that require other `.pl` files and there are no packages. Now a package becomes a problem, because if there usually are none and there is no `Exporter`ing going on, stuff gets weird.

I have often needed to contain legacy code with lots of globals inside of packages to hide them away from my `main` namespace.

```
package DoNotPutGlobalsInMyMain { require 'legacy.pl' };
```

But if there is is an explicit definition of another `package` inside of `legacy.pl` this will break. So my above statement still stands. You need controll of that code to fix it, or know which package *really* contains the sub you want to call.

Then you can `use` or `require` that package yourself. As long as `foo.pm` has already loaded it, it will not get loaded again (because Perl made a note in `%INC` that it has loaded it). But if upstream they remove it from `foo.pm` it will still be available. Also your maintenance programmer understands what your dependencies are.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load `DEF.pm` and access it as `bar` you can do this via typeglob:

http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Typeglobs-and-Filehandles

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#Symbol-Tables

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package DEF; 

sub routine {
    print "Routine called\n";
} 

package main;

local *foo::routine = *DEF::routine;
foo::routine();
```

This'll work for a single sub from a package to change the symbol table.

But I'd actually question why you need to do this? Do you have two clashing namespaces or something? It's quite a good way to make code messier, rather than cleaner, so I wouldn't generally suggest it as a good idea.

Otherwise - you can use a code reference:

```
my $ref_to_routine = \&DEF::routine;

$ref_to_routine->();
&$ref_to_routine();
```

Comment: I think OP means something else. I also thought this and posted an answer I have already deleted. But if you check the last part of the question you'll see there are packages inside of the packages. And that is something else.

Answer (score 1):

Your modules don't actually export anything.

`ABC.pm`:

```
package ABC;
use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT = qw( routine );
sub routine { return __PACKAGE__ }
```

`DEF.pm`:

```
package DEF;
use Exporter qw( import );
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( routine );
sub routine { return __PACKAGE__ }
```

`script`:

```
package foo;
use ABC qw( routine );

package bar;
use DEF qw( routine );

package main;
print foo::routine(), "\n";   # ABC
print bar::routine(), "\n";   # DEF
```

You could also use something like the following:

```
use ABC qw( );
use DEF qw( );
BEGIN {
   *foo_routine = \&ABC::routine;   # Could use foo::routine if you wanted.
   *bar_routine = \&DEF::routine;
}

print foo_routine(), "\n";   # ABC
print bar_routine(), "\n";   # DEF
```

`use Module ()` and `use Module qw()` prevents the module's `import` from being called. The modules here don't define any default exports, but I like to be explicit about what I import.